# jquery modal dialog seo friendly

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

Is jQuery modal dialog seo friendly? If not what changes can we make so that the content inside modal dialog can be easily read by the crawler?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: Sorry forgot to mention that the content in the modal is coming from server side. so it is using ajax as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your dialog content just lives in the page and is "turned into a jquery modal dialog", then it will be part of the data that a crawler could access...If the content is loaded through ajax etc then that wouldn't be indexed as it requires javascript to run to populate the html.

```
...
<body>
<div id="MyModalDialog">
   This is content I want the search engine to index. As it exists in the page without needing any javascript to exist here, it could be indexed.
</div>
<input value="Show Dialog" id="ShowDialog" />
</body>
...
```

**Edit**
If the content requires javascript in **any** way and it wasn't already part of the original request, then you can basically assume a crawler will not index it.

**Edit 2**
If you wanted a strategy to overcome this. If you used a html link to open the dialog, provided the link opened the url correctly then you could always have a fallback for browsers/clients/crawlers that do not have javascript enabled, and then the content could be indexed...but it would be indexed under the original url...one that you might not want people entering your site against...

Something like this:

```
<div id="dialog">
</div>
<a href="/page/to/index/content" class="open-dialog">Open Dialog</a>
```

and the script

```
$(function() {

   $("a.open-dialog").click(function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();

       // get the url that this link is going to open
       var url = $(this).attr("href");

       // put contents in div and show dialog
       $("#dialog").load(url).dialog({modal:true});
   });

});
```

So a crawler would just follow the link from the a tag to the other content and potentially index it...hope that makes sense...otherwise the jquery code would cancel the link click and open the contents in the dialog.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention that the content in the modal is coming from server side. so it is using ajax as well.

Comment: @Kin, can it come from the server side at the time the "host" page is generated by the browser?

Comment: @davidsleeps no :( it is user requested, so when user clicks on a url, then the data is being fetched from the server. If I load it on page load, the site will slow down because of huge amount of data.

Comment: @Kin, here's a possible work around...I might not have got it right though...it's all basically pseudo code.

Comment: @davidsleeps I think this will work definitely. My only concern is, google will start showing up "/page/to/index/content" in search results? But I think I can use your idea to some extent and modify it to work for me. Thanks.

Comment: @Kin, you might be able to perform some javascript redirect on those indexed pages for a certain condition (referrer is google, yahoo, bing etc e.g. from a search engine) back to your main page or even provide a link on each of those indexed pages which takes you to the main page...this link could be hidden when viewed within the dialog

Comment: davidsleeps is champ :). Now this is perfect solution.